# Storing a Set of Integer values in Sql Server 2005 with nHibernate?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

What is the best way to store and map an Entity which contains a set of Integer as one of its attributes? I am using nHibernate over Sql Server 2005.

Will creating a CLR Custom Type will help here? If yes how it can be mapped using nHibernate?

I should be able to query on the Set. E.g.

```
select myEntity from MyEntities where myEntity.Integers = SetOf(2, 4, 5)
```

Comment: "One of its attributes": do you mean fields or properties? What do you mean by "CLR Custom Type"?

Comment: @Stefan: I mean Properties. CLR is in built into Sql Server 2005 and we can create Custom Types

Comment: When you use NHibernate, I would generally stick to NHibernate features, which makes you more independent of Sql Server and reduces development costs. There are user types for NHibernate, but they aren't used here. This question sounds pretty basic to me, unless I missed something. **EDIT:** In the comment on my question I see that you need specific queries. Add them to the question, is is essential.

Comment: Should all the items in the Set match? So the set should be contain the exact same items? Sets are by definition not ordered, so the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes order should not matter and all the items must match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this class

```
class MyEntity
{
  //...
  public IList<int> Integers { get; private set; }
}
```

Just map it as a set.

```
<class name="MyEntity">
  <!-- ... -->
  <set name="Integers" table="MyEntity_Integers">
    <key column="MyEntity_FK"/>
    <element type="Int32" column="Value"/>
  </set>
</class>
```

You could try to filter the collection by:

```
from MyEntity e 
where e.Integers in (:set) 
  and size(e.Integers) = :setSize
```

This is probably not very fast.

---

A completely different approach: store the integers in some serialized form into a single text field.

You could write your own NHibernate custom type. Sort the integers before storing. You could store them in a format like `"2;45;78;898"`. Filtering will be very fast, because it just matches the string. Changing the collection in the database could get hard. Another problem is that the column length is limited.

[Here is an example](http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx) of a NHibernate user type implementation.

Comment: It is one of the way but I also need to be able to query on the Set. Like where MyEntity.Integers == SetOf(2,3,5)

Comment: This is a different question. You can't make an optimal mapping for any query. You need to tell me which kind of queries you need to perform on these data structure.